# Change the "beta" site name?

Tags: discussion, site-name, beta

Given everything, I'm inclined to request that we change our "beta" site name from "Statistical Analysis" to "Data Analysis", and the respective subdomain from "stats" to "data".  I think this would be more fitting for how the site has evolved.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sorry, `data` is reserved for our network.

We will be moving http://odata.stackexchange.com to http://data.stackexchange.com

"Data" meaning, the creative commons data dumps of all sites in our network.

now complete, see:
http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/12/re-launching-stack-exchange-data-explorer/

Comment: That's a bummer, although I understand why you would want to keep data for this purpose.

Comment: Oh well, thanks for letting us know so promptly.

Comment: So I thought... not to mention it is on the other hand too broad.

Answer (score 5):

Is it worth it given that we move out of beta (and presumably to a new URL and site-name) in 48 days? The change will last about 6 weeks at most. It is obviously important that the new *permanent* name and URL are seen to be inclusive of statisticians as well as those in the data mining community.

Answer (score 3):

**Agree with Q**. I honestly had precisely the same thought myself before I saw this Q.

I think it's a good time to revive this topic, in light of more recent developments on the current likelihood or otherwise of changing the site name (see [this question](https://stats.meta.stackexchange.com/q/472/449)), and as [according to area51](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/33/statistical-analysis) we've just finished our beta phase and *"will be launching very soon"* (yey!).

Comment: As we are apparently no longer allowed to have CrossValidated.com, I agree -- Data Analysis reflects the nature of the site better than Statistical Analysis.

Comment: @Rob We don't know it yet. Cooking showed some compromise is possible.

Comment: Beta ended, yes, but we won't start soon. We have no design and SE team seems to have other problems now.

Answer (score 0):

I think Data Analysis is a better name than Statistical Analysis. Even better is maybe "Data Science" what do you think?

Comment: My understanding of 'Data Science' would be much broader, encompassing computer science, information science, data management...

Comment: I might be in the minority, but I don't like the term.  Beyond which I think that it has mostly been invented to cover "big data" problems, so it would actually limit the scope of the site.

Comment: @Shane good point.

Answer (score 0):

If we can't have `data.` then how about **`data-anal.`** ?

*Data Anal.* is used as the abbreviation for "data analysis" in journal titles such as *Lifetime Data Analysis*, *Intelligent Data Analysis*, *Advances in Data Analysis and Classification*, ...

Comment: The anal abbreviation has other interpretations. Probably best to avoid that.

Comment: I agree with Rob; the hyphen isn't a great idea either (IMO).  Maybe just analysis.SE?  Or else leave it as stats.SE.  We have CrossValidated as the site name, so that's something.

Comment: analysis.SE would be far too ambiguous. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Analysis.